# Alterar dados de objeto que está numa lista

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Na minha aplicação, há uma lista encadeada de elementos. Preciso realizar uma operação para alterar um dado do elemento escolhido. A pergunta é: posso fazer desta forma como fiz abaixo buscando o objeto e alterando o dado ali mesmo ou preciso acessar o objeto direto da lista e alterá-lo lá? Se eu fizer uma alteração no objeto fora da lista, o objeto que está dentro sofre a alteração também?

```
        Nodo origem = anel.buscar_nodo(msg.id_origem);
        origem.msg_e.Add(msg);
```

Comment: Pode ou não pode? Quando você debugou, o que aconteceu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR:

> Se eu fizer uma alteração no objeto fora da lista, o objeto que está dentro sofre a alteração também?

Sim

### Explicação

Os objetos que criamos são do Tipo Referência (ler [Ref Type vs Value Type](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm)), funciona como um ponteiro: a variável na verdade aponta pro endereço em memória no qual estão os valores do objeto, portanto quando alteramos o valor da variável, estamos alterando na verdade o valor no qual a variável está referenciando.

Então se fizermos algo como `Nodo origem2 = origem1;` não estamos copiando o valor da `origem1` pra `origem2`, estamos dizendo:

> "origem2, agora você irá apontar para o mesmo endereço que a origem1 está apontando."

Logo, ao alterar uma propriedade de `origem1` (que na verdade é alterar o valor no qual ela aponta), isso será refletido na `origem2`, que aponta para o mesmo objeto.